# What is the consequence to customers of removing an iPhone app from the store

Tags: iphone, app-store

If we remove one of our apps from the iPhone app store what is the effect on all the people who have previously purchased the app. In other words if they change devices, or lose their phone and sign in with the same account used to buy our app, will they still be able to download it from the store? Or is it completely eliminated from Apple's servers?

Comment: I'm torn on whether to close this one or not, even though I'm violently opposed to the Apple lock-down, one of the few things actually _worse_ than DRM :-) The reason - it appears to gel with the FAQ category "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" since I can't see this question being asked by anyone other than a developer. So I'm going to vote to keep it.

Comment: Violence is against the Stack Overflow community guidelines. ;)

Comment: There is a new checkbox in iTunes Connect asking if an app was updated due to legal problems.  It is quite possible that a customer who had an old version of such an app might not be able to (re)download that version again, and any newer version may not run on their device's current OS version.

Comment: If I have violated some rule of Stackoverflow can you let me know what it is as I can't really figure out what you are saying in these comments. My reason for asking my question here was because I thought this was a Q&A for developers. I'm simply trying to be cautious with our customers and I am not making any judgements about Apple. And I would expect other developers would like to know what happens when you remove an app from the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should still be able to download it even if they switch devices after you pull it from the store.

http://www.macrumors.com/2011/06/09/icloud-supports-re-downloading-some-discontinued-apps/

Comment: This link is helpful because it seems to say re-downloading is available when an app is removed. It seems to be focused on legal reasons for removing an app which is not really my issue; our reasons are simply the product is getting old and we want to do some thing really new and different. I would think there are many developers who have this situation. One thing not explained in the link: is the re-downloadable feature available in older versions of iOS? Regardless thanks so much for your help.